# The Distributor has not been installed correctly. Could not enable database for publishing

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, replication, aws-dms

I am using an **AWS-DMS instance to migrate and replicate an on-premises database** to another SQL instance in the AWS cloud.

When I use a migration task of type Full load, the instance successfully executes the migration, but with the same Mapping rules and Tasks migrations of types Full load and/or ongoing replication they fail:

**Last failure message**

> Last Error Fatal error has occurred Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2859] [1022505] Failed (retcode -1) to execute statement; RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 42000 NativeError: 20028 Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]

**The Distributor has not been installed correctly. Could not enable database for publishing.**

> Line: 1 Column: -1; Failed while preparing stream component 'st_0_6SULBUTK4MXZHA6HQ'.; Cannot initialize subtask; Stream component 'st_0_6SULBUTK434OZAJOXANFLHA6HQ' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2866] [1022505] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

Answer (score 4):

The Distributor has not been installed correctly. Could not enable database for publishing.", which indicates that source is not correctly configured to allow for ongoing replication based on Distributor has not been installed correctly.

To check if distribution has already been configured, run the following command when connect to the source server.

***sp_get_distributor***

If the result is NULL for column distribution, distribution isn't configured.Please note that, you can use either MS-Replication or MS-CDC to enable continuous replication for on-prem SQL server. You may please use MS-Replication for the tables with primary keys and for the tables without primary keys , you can choose to enable MS-CDC at the database and the individual table level

To have the MS-replicaiton, the distribution database has to be configured as per the steps discussed and mentioned below:

### To set up distribution

=>Connect to your SQL Server source database using the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) tool.

=>Open the context (right-click) menu for the Replication folder, and choose Configure Distribution. The Configure Distribution Wizard appears.

=>Follow the wizard to enter the default values and create the distribution.You can use the following procedure to set up distribution.

Once the distribution database is set up, DMS should be able to create a publication and then be able to add articles to the publication. Followed by which the task should be able to continue with the replication.